# How to terminate thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Here I am creating 3 threads for one server and 2 clients. I wanted to stop the thread and make the port numbers reusable after one execution. My code is

```
t1=threading.Thread(target=serv)
t2=threading.Thread(target=cli1)
t3=threading.Thread(target=cli2)

t1.start()
time.sleep(2)
t2.start()
time.sleep(2)
t1.start()
time.sleep(2)
```

Here `serv`, `cli1` and `cli2` are the functions that contains client server programs.

How do I terminate these threads ?

Comment: please see the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your serv cli1 and cli2 functions so they terminate themselves if a flag which you will set in your main thread is set.